# Can a clickonce application know what directory it was installed from?

Tags: vb.net, path, installation, clickonce

First, long time reader, first time poster.

Let's say that you have 2 clickonce folders, Prod and Dev.
If the application is installed from Prod you want it to access database ABC_Prod.
If the application is installed from Dev you want it to access database ABC_Dev.

Is there a way for the running clickonce application to know what folder it was installed from?  A manifest or config that contains this?
I'm not looking for what directory the application is running from, but installed from.

Thanks

Comment: The application could be installed from any folder, so that's a rather silly way to control run-time behaviour. It would be far more appropriate for you to create two separate installation packages with that functionality built into the package.

Comment: Maybe use build configurations.  Deploy a debug build then you can use the debug compiler directive to switch your connection string.  Not sure if this works in a click once though

Comment: I ask because a customer of our does this with their code, that we have to use.  When the application starts it has a hard coded database and server to look for.  Each location, we are a location, has a code.  That code is used to lookup some configuration in the master database.  So between that code and the url install path it knows which database table to access for location specific information.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.

`Imports System.Deployment.Application`

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            TextBox1.Text = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.LocalPath
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class